# Need hints proving $\operatorname{rank}(T)+\operatorname{nullity}(T)=\operatorname{dim}(U)$

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the reasoning behind this theorem? If $T:U \rightarrow V$ is a linear map then $\operatorname{nullity}(T)+\operatorname{rank}(T) =\operatorname{dim}(U)$.
I am trying to prove it and looking for hints.

Comment: A good idea would be to point out what $U$, $V$ and $T$ are. I'm assuming vector spaces and a vector space homomorphism? I'm also assuming that the little $u$ should be a capital $U$? If you're working in full generality the first things you want to do is write down the definitions. I would also consider checking if you know anything about quotient spaces.

Comment: Consider general bases

Comment: This is proved in most texts on linear algebra and most course in linear algebra

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\;U,\,V\;$ are linear spaces and $\;\dim U=n<\infty\;$ , here are some hints for you to work out and prove:

== Choose a basis $\;\{u_1,...,u_k\}\;$ of $\;\ker T\;$ (and thus $\;Null\, T=\dim\ker T=k\;$)

== Complete the above basis to a basis of $\;U\,:\;\;\{u_1,...,u_k,u_{k+1},...,u_n\}\;$ .

== Prove now that $\;\{Tu_{k+1},...,Tu_n\}\;$ is a basis for Im$\,T\;$ (and thus we have that $\;Rank\,T=\dim\text{Im}\,T=n-k\,$)

== Complete, and end, the proof.

Another option, of course, is to look for the proof in thousands of sites and books that deal with basic linear algebra.